# Expressão regular para validar texto

Tags: c#, regex

Eu estou fazendo um método que vai importar uns dados, e antes da importação eu preciso verificar se alguns campos estão corretamente preenchidos, os campos devem vir dessa maneira:

Exemplo:

```
Jan/Seg
Fev/Ter
Mar/Qui
```

Os dados precisam estar nesse exato formato, aonde os 3 primeiros caracteres representam o prefixo do mês, seguido de uma barra e logo após 3 caracteres que representam o dia da semana.

Preciso verificar se o prefixo do mês e valido e se o prefixo da semana também, e precisa conter os dois, pensei em fazer uma regex que faça isso, porém não sei como fazer em `C#`, alguém sabe uma boa forma de se fazer isso? 
Desde já muito obrigado.

Comment: Como vem os dados? Os dados válidos são apenas aqueles cujas linhas tem 7 caracteres, sendo os 3 primeiros o prefixo do mês, o quarto a barra e os últimos 3 caracteres o prefixo do dia da semana?

Comment: Exatamento, os dados vão vir de uma planilha do excel e precisam estar nesse exato formato, vou adicionar na pergunta essa informação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei como é feito no C#, mas a Regular Expression poderia ser assim:

```
^(Jan|Fev|Mar|Abr|Mai|Jun|Jul|Aug|Set|Out|Nov|Dez)\/(Seg|Ter|Qua|Qui|Sex|Sab|Dom)$
```

que ela conseguirá validar para você

Comment: Pode ser bobeira minha, mas acho que por os delimitadores `^` e `$` garantiria que a linha contém apenas isso. Veja a atualização na pergunta, a linha precisa ser exatamente isso.

Comment: Sim concordo, ficaria mais específico

Comment: Tomei então a liberdade de fazê-lo

Comment: Dá pra reduzir algumas coisas: Março e Maio podem ser condensados com `Ma[ri]` (`Ma` seguido de `r` ou `i`). Da mesma forma, Julho e Julho podem ser `Ju[ln]` e Quarta e Quinta, `Qu[ai]`, e Segunda e Sexta, `Se[gx]`, veja [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/39aiUl/2). Mas a sua regex tb está certa :-) E usar `^` e `$` não é apenas para deixar "mais específico", neste caso é o ideal já que as linhas devem ter somente esse conteúdo, e não usá-los causaria falsos positivos (a linha poderia ter outros caracteres antes ou depois e seria considerada válida).

Comment: @hkotsubo eu ainda acho que regex é desnecessário pra esse caso :) Acho que verificação de string pode ser mais simples e rápida

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Concordo, regex nem sempre é a melhor solução para tudo :-)